# Count the frequency of occurrence of a certain row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame with 3 columns as

```
     date        amount     type
0   20160101     50        apple 
1   20160101     50        apple  
2   20160101     50        banana 
3   20160102     30        apple        
4   20160102     50        apple
5   20160102     40        banana
6   20160102     40        banana
```

What I want to do is to count the frequency of the occurrence of a row using all the columns, and the result should be something like

```
date      amount      type      times
20160101   50         apple     2
20160101   50         banana    1
20160102   30         apple     1
20160102   50         apple     1
20160102   40         banana    2
```

My code is like

```
df
Out[23]: 
       Date  Amount    Type
0  20160101      50   apple
1  20160101      50   apple
2  20160101      50  banana
3  20160102      30   apple
4  20160102      50   apple
5  20160102      40  banana
6  20160102      40  banana

P=df.pivot_table('Amount','Date','Type')

P
Out[27]: 
Type      apple  banana
Date                   
20160101     50      50
20160102     40      40
```

Comment: Did you try any solution?

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this? = yes.   What have you tried?

Comment: @NagarajTantri I only know how to count the frequency of a certain value occurs but that's not what I want.

Comment: @xzt not an issue, always show what have you tried to get to a solution. Because, SO is basically about, `you gave a shot` at it and yet need some help over `getting the bulls eye`.

Comment: @NagarajTantri Just added it to the question.

Comment: @glls Just added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that will get you your answer. I feel like there needs to be a more direct way though

```
df['times'] = 1
df.groupby(['Date', 'Amount', 'Type'], as_index=False).sum()
```

EDIT:

found a second solution (you need to rename the column

```
df.groupby(['date','type']).amount.value_counts().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> df.groupby(['date', 'amount', 'type']).size().reset_index()
       date  amount    type  0
0  20160101      50   apple  2
1  20160101      50  banana  1
2  20160102      30   apple  1
3  20160102      40  banana  2
4  20160102      50   apple  1
```

or you can use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once).

> If a dict is passed, the keys will be used to name the columns. Otherwise the function’s name (stored in the function object) will be used.

```
df.groupby(['date', 'amount', 'type']).type.agg({'times': 'size'}).reset_index()
       date  amount    type  times
0  20160101      50   apple      2
1  20160101      50  banana      1
2  20160102      30   apple      1
3  20160102      40  banana      2
4  20160102      50   apple      1
```

Comment: Maybe better is use `df.groupby(['date', 'amount', 'type']).size().reset_index(name='times')`

Comment: Or `df.groupby(['date', 'amount', 'type'], sort=False).size().reset_index(name='times')`

Comment: Thanks! And I was wondering is there anyway I can show the result in a histogram? I tried to use .plot(kind='hist'), but the plot looked wired.